# what is the actual range in the range function of python

Tags: python-3.x

#### in the following syntax the range function must give 4 values. So, if the trail ==3 it must be the third attempt. But I had to give the trail ==4 for printing the  "your account is a locked statement". I got a little confused here.

otp = "1945"

for trail in range (1,5):

```
if trail ==4:
    print("your account has been locked")
    break
if trail==3:
    print ("one attempt left")

enter_otp=input("enter your otp: ")
if enter_otp!=otp:
    print("re enter the otp")
    
else:
    name=input("enter your name")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

Answer (score 0):

for trail in range(1,5) then it will start from 1 and end at 4 and it can also written as range(4) which iterate form 0 to 3.

```
otp="1945"
for trail in range(1,5):
    enter_otp=input("Enter your otp:")
    if enter_otp!=otp:
        print("re enter the otp")

        if trail==4:
                print("Your account has been locked")
        if trail==3:
                print("One attempt left")

    if enter_otp==otp:
        name=input("Enter your name:")
    break
```